# How to pass a model to data-url in bootstrap table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am using - [Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/)

I cannot figure out, how do i pass a model to the `data-url` property of `bootstrap-table` ?

My Razor Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>

<table id="myTable" data-url=......">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="MyProperty">
                Some Example
            </th>
            <th data-field="MyProperty2">
                Some Example
            </th>
            <th data-field="MyProperty3">
                Some Example
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

My Controller Code -  just in case.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMyValues()
{
    List<MyTable> myList = myObj.GetValues();
    return PartialView("MyPartialView", myList);
}
```

Comment: what value you are trying to set?

Comment: values from my List which comes in to the model(in razor)

Comment: you want to set which item value, it is not clear, where are you stuck?

Comment: i want to pass that model in data-url

Comment: it is a bad idea, why you want that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert your Model i.e IEnumerable using below code

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));
```

then bind this data to html table

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data
    });
});
```

Comment: it wont work...i can say that: It has more to do with how the `bootstrap-table` works. Anyway, why would i want to set a single property on a table.

Comment: when we set the data-url - the whole tr acts like a for loop. So `@Model[0].MyProperty` will only set the first value in the list.

Comment: Ohhh, You then need to convert Ienumerable to json

Comment: and then pass `data` to `data-url`??

Comment: in this link, they have used one function to bind data to html table, you can check there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81930/discussion-between-user2281858-and-nitin-varpe).